# Automatic type deduction failure with brace initialisation in a function call with unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr, list-initialization

Given the code below, what is the difference between unique_ptr and Bar that made `bar ( { new int } );` ok but not `foo( { new int } );`

```
#include <memory>

struct Bar {
    Bar() = default;
    Bar( int* m ) : m_( m ) {};
    ~Bar() { if ( m_ ) delete m_; }
    explicit operator bool() const { return m_; }
private:
    int* m_ {};
};

bool bar( Bar && a ) { return bool(a); }
bool foo( std::unique_ptr<int> && a) { return bool(a); }

int main() {
    bar( { } );            // ok
    bar( Bar{ new int } ); // ok
    bar( { new int } );    // ok

    foo( { } );                             // ok
    foo( std::unique_ptr<int>{ new int } ); // ok
    foo( { new int } );                     // compile error
}
```

The compilation error with clang 3.5 :

```
+ clang++ -std=c++1y -O3 -W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pthread main.cpp
main.cpp:22:5: error: no matching function for call to 'foo'
foo( { new int } );                     // compile error
^~~
main.cpp:13:6: note: candidate function not viable: cannot convert initializer list argument to 'std::unique_ptr<int>'
bool foo( std::unique_ptr<int> && a) { return bool(a); }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The single-argument pointer constructor of `unique_ptr` is `explicit`:

```
explicit unique_ptr( pointer p );
```

Comment: I looked at the documentation on cppreference.com to check that and did not see it even in front of my eyes. Thanks anyway, time to rest…